# how to correctly process an image

Tags: image-processing

OBS: All pseudo code or real code (except brainfuck) are accepted as response

Assuming that I have a black and white logo, as a picture file, where there is some noise (not 100% black and white and no pixels are 100% black too)

If I wanted to change the black to another predefined color how would I go about that?

I have tried to find the difference between the true white pixels and the other and tried to shift the pixel in that favor, but it ends some total noise.

Comment: Please share your image and the expected result. Please also show your latest/greatest code.

Comment: Can you tell the color of my car ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Adaptive thresholding to convert your image to a binary image.
Then map black and white to desire color.

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
image = cv2.cvtColor(th2,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
image[image==(255,255,255)] = (255,0,0) # RED
image[image==(0,0,0)] = (0,255,0) # GREEN
```

Comment: Thanks. it has been a long time since I did anything with an image.